# How to resize webview content after load the second page in Android?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a `webView` inside a `scrollview`, when I load a page, the view show correctly. But when I turn to another `webView` page, `webView` doesn't change height automatically, and there is a large empty area at the bottom of `webView`.
How to resolve it or is there a good implement of webView poll ?

Comment: webview have own scrollview, not need of any scrollview, also make height  wrap_content of webview.

Comment: I need to make it scroll with other android native webview. How to do it?